# Make switch stay same color when on and off

Tags: android, android-view, android-switch

I'm trying to make an Android Switch act as just a selection between two options, so I want to make it so that the switch is the same color when it's 'on' as when it's 'off'.
How do I do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add this to Styles.xml:

```
<style name="SelectionSwitch" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- active thumb & track color (30% transparency) -->
    <item name="colorControlActivated">#f1f1f1</item>

    <!-- inactive thumb color -->
    <item name="colorSwitchThumbNormal">#f1f1f1
    </item>

    <!-- inactive track color (30% transparency) -->
    <item name="android:colorForeground">#42221f1f
    </item>
</style>
```

and add the Switch to to your layout as below:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:theme="@style/SelectionSwitch" />
```

Comment: Thanks got me on the right track! I ended up just setting all 3 of those colors to `@color/colorPrimary` to make it truly the same color on and off. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't have styles.xml file

Comment: I added it to themes.xml. I think I need to add the same to the dark theme and change the parent to parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight" in both themes?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [SwitchCompat component](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/SwitchCompat.html) with a custom style:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/SwitchStyle"/>
```

In your res/value/style.xml file define the style

```
<style name="SwitchStyle">
    <item name="colorSwitchThumbNormal">@color/color_switch_off</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/color_switch_on</item>
</style>
```

Hope this helps.